# Creating a JWT with Public Key in PHP

Tags: php, jwt, rsa

im creating a JWT with the following script which works fine, i just need to figure out how to use the RSA Signature with a Public and Private Key. Can anybody help? :(

Right now im just using a secret, which is the wrong way i guess...

```
function generate_jwt($headers, $payload, $secret = 'x3dnSBBSDjkm2nbsd74090dfhasbdxjkUIJBKMsd8723JGad') {
    $headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));
    $payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
    
    $signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $secret, true);
    $signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);
    
    $jwt = "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
    
    return $jwt;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a valid JWT in PHP using RSA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67325893/how-to-create-a-valid-jwt-in-php-using-rsa256)

Comment: or this? [PHP JWT (JSON Web Token) with RSA signature without library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66986631)

Comment: Using a pre-shared secret isn't "wrong", it just depends on your use case. If you need your tokens to be verifiable without sharing that secret around, then public key cryptography would be what you want. At this point you should do yourself a favor and use a library to handle JWT generation/validation, otherwise you're likely to go off into the weeds dealing with the minutiae. Not to mention that there are a fair number of common, easy mistakes you can make that break your implementation.

Comment: The two top libs would be [jose](https://github.com/gree/jose) and [firebase](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) which are respectively based on PHPseclib and OpenSSL for JWS generation.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answers. I need to send a jwt string to an url. To veryify, the url provider needs a public key and thats what i need to implement... Still need to use the lib for this case?

Comment: You don't _need_ to, but I recommend it. You can certainly cobble together your own implementation with the code behind jps' links.