# PHP - read a private key file ".key" to use for JWT

Tags: php, json, jwt

I have a private key file `$formatPrivateKey` that I need to use as a variable

```
$privateKey =  file_get_contents('27660275_website.com.key');

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base64UrlHeader . "." . $base64UrlPayload, $privateKey, true);
```

I need this to generate a client-assertion JWT.

However, I'm getting the following error - `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA"}`

I guess I'm not reading the `file_get_contents('27660275_website.com.key')` properly.

My `$privateKey` file starts with the following `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and finishes with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----`. I tried to remove them but I still got the same output.

I tried to concatenate the alphanumeric sequence as suggested in another answer to a question in Stackoverflow. However, it didn't work.

Therefore my assumption that I'm not reading `file_get_contents('27660275_website.com.key')` properly.

Comment: What information are you missing so that you would not guess any longer but know? What is your rationale behind using file_get_contens() on the file to read the key out of it? Hitting and hitting it again until it does not move any longer?

Comment: The "alphanumeric sequence" in your .key file is not the actual key, but a textual (base64 encoded) representation of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the secret key is a password (a string) rather than a private key file.

Check out this for example, they simply use the password 'secret'. Any string should make your code work.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. i'M following the documentation on 
 https://developer.revolut.codes/docs/manage-accounts/#introduction-to-the-business-api and the documentation states " The client-assertion JWT should be signed with your private key."

Comment: @MtDemonics: What prevents you from signing the JWT? Where did you obtain the code in your question from and what is your understanding of what it does?

Comment: I got the code from here - https://dev.to/robdwaller/how-to-create-a-json-web-token-using-php-3gml and I modified it to fit Revolut's documentation here - https://developer.revolut.codes/docs/manage-accounts/#get-started-get-started-make-your-first-api-request-4-exchange-authorization-code-for-access-token The token is being generated but its not being accepted by Revolut.

Comment: I think I see the issue. You don't need to read all of this, but hmac uses a secret shared between both parties, while ECDSA and RSA use private/public keys.

More here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30657/hmac-vs-ecdsa-for-jwt

So you need to encrypt using RSA or ECDSA. I'm not familiar with PHP, but you could potentially use this library? https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt

Comment: Actually I think this provides a better answer (use RSA): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986631/php-jwt-json-web-token-with-rsa-signature-without-library